# Overfull \hbox (1.90002pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active

Tags: citing

I am getting these two messages:

```
Overfull \hbox (1.90002pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active

Underfull \hbox (badness 5203) in paragraph at lines 9--12
```

I don't know where the first message gomes from but the second one is caused by the citation!

```
\documentclass[5p,preprint]{elsarticle}

\journal{Energy}
\setcitestyle{square}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=whatever}

\begin{document}

 
\begin{frontmatter}
%% Title, authors and addresses
 \title{Latex }
 
 \author[aa,ab]{Author A}
 \ead{Author1@Latex.edu}
 
 \author[ab]{Author2 B}
 \ead{author2@Latex.edu}
 
 \author[ab]{Author3 C\corref{cor}}
 \ead{Author3@Latex.edu} 
 \cortext[cor]{Corresponding author}

 \address[aa]{Department of Latex Engineering, University of Latex}
 \address[ab]{Department of Latex2 Engineering, University of Latex2}

 
\begin{abstract}
 Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex    
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}
Latex Latex Latex  Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex Latex \cite{xu2010hydraulic}


\biboptions{sort&compress}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{citation.bib}

\end{document}

\endinput
```

my citation

```
@inproceedings{xu2010hydraulic,
  title={Hydraulic transmission electromagnetic energy-regenerative active suspension and its working principle},
  author={Xu, Lin and Guo, Xuexun},
  booktitle={2010 2nd International Workshop on Intelligent Systems and Applications},
  pages={1--5},
  year={2010},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

can you please help me to clear these messages

Answer (score 3):

The underful box message is because LaTeX can't find a good line break for that first line of the bibliography message and that, in turn, is because TeX will not normally hyphenate words that are part of a compound. You have two options:

- Ignore the warning. It's not that big of a deal, especially with narrow columns. If it really bothers you to see the warning, add `\hbadness=6000` to your document (in the preamble to have it impact everything, to just before `\bibliography` to have it only impact the citations.
- Add an explicit hyphenation to your title, e.g., `energy-regen\-erative`. It's up to you or your editor whether the extra spacing is worse or the hyphenation of a hyphenated compound is worse.

The `overfull \hbox` message is being generated by the page footer (add `\overfullrule=1pt` to the document preamble to have TeX show you where it's going beyond its boundaries). A bit more digging and you're doing nothing wrong, it appears to be a bug in the `elsarticle` document class. Adding `\hfuzz=2pt` to the document preamble will turn off the warning message. You can report the bug (line 697 needs a `%` after the `}` to `elsarticle@stmdocs.in` according to the readme file.

Comment: Thank you so much